# How to bind QLineEdit with sqlite Database?

Tags: qt

I want to save data into sqlite database from QLineEdit. How to bind with QlineEdit ? Please explain.

Here is my code: it does not work

```
**QString user_name = ui->txt_UserName->text ();
    QString pass = ui->txt_Pass->text ();

    QSqlQuery query;
    query.prepare ("CREATE TABLE login_info("
                                "user_id text primary key,"
                                "pass text)"
                   );
    query.prepare ("INSERT INTO login_info (user_id) VALUES('shajksfl')");
    query.prepare ("DELETE FROM login_info");
    query.bindValue (":user_name", user_name);

    query.prepare ("SELECT * FROM login_info");

    if(!query.exec ()){
        //
        qDebug() << query.lastInsertId ();
        QMessageBox::critical (this, "Eror!", "Unable to save data.", QMessageBox::Ok, QMessageBox::Cancel);
    } else {

        QMessageBox::information (this, "Success!", "Success to save data.", QMessageBox::Ok, QMessageBox::Cancel);

        while(query.next ()){
            QString usr = query.value (0).toString ();
            QString pswd = query.value (1).toString ();

            qDebug() << usr << pswd << endl;
        }
    }**
```

it works if i insert manually.

Answer (score 0):

If by "bind" you mean automatically save to database when text changes, and/or update the text when database changes, then this is not possible natively, you will have to code it.

If you simply want to bind a value in an SQL query (i.e simply set a value in your query in a secure way, by replacing a token), then this is what you should do:

```
query.prepare ("INSERT INTO login_info (user_id) VALUES(:user_name)");
query.bindValue (":user_name", user_name);
```

This will replace ":user_name" by the value contained in your `user_name` variable, adding quotes and everything needed.

Note additionally that you cannot use `prepare` multiple times, and then `exec`. You have to call `exec` after each prepared query. Please have a look at [Qt documentation page](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#prepare) that shows an example.

Comment: Thank you. It works. how to display data into qtableview ?

Comment: Happy to hear that. For a QTableView, you would have to use a `QSqlTableModel` or your own model. An other way is to use a QTableWidget. But this would go in a different question ! :) Please tag the correct answer to you, and open a new one if you like.

Answer (score 0):

You use several "prepare()" without execute it, and you bind without use placeholders.
Look the Qt documentation [QSqlQuery::prepare(const QString&)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#prepare)

```
QString user_id = txt_UserName->text();
QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare("INSERT INTO login_info (user_id) VALUES(':user_id')");
query.bindValue(":user_id", user_id);
query.exec();
```

If you want execute another query, you have to prepare another statement.
With your code, your exec method do this query : `DELETE FROM login_info`
So it can't work.
Regards